# Update a dictionary value using python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file, which when loaded in python using `json.loads()` becomes a `dictionary`. The json data is a `nested dictionary` which can contain a `'groups'` key inside another `'groups'` key. The values inside the `'groups'` key are a `'name'` key and a `'properties'` key.

Each `'properties'` key has a unique `'name'` and a `'value'` key.

My objective is to search for a `'groups'` key having its `'name'` key value as `"SportCar"`, which has a `properties` key having a `name` key value as `"BMW"`, and only when these conditions are satisfied, update the `'data'` key from `'data':value1` to `'data':value2`.

An example of the json is as follows

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "SportCar",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "BMW",
          "value": {
            "type": "String",
            "encoding": "utf-8",
            "data": "value1"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Audi",
          "value": {
            "type": "Boolean",
            "data": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "Trucks",
          "properties": [
            {
              "name": "Volvo",
              "value": {
                "type": "String",
                "encoding": "utf-8",
                "data": "value1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "MotorCycle",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "Yamaha",
          "value": {
            "type": "String",
            "encoding": "utf-8",
            "data": "value1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "Speeders",
          "properties": [
            {
              "name": "prop2",
              "value": {
                "type": "String",
                "encoding": "utf-8",
                "data": "value1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The above json is contained in myjson22.json. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_data=open('myjson22.json', 'r')
data = json.load(json_data)
#print(data)

def get_recursively(search_dict, field):
    """
    To read the json data as type dict and search all 'groups' keys for the 'name' key value value provided.
    """
    fields_found = []

    for key, value in search_dict.items():

        if key == field:
            fields_found.append(value)

        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            results = get_recursively(value, field)
            for result in results:
                fields_found.append(result)

        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    more_results = get_recursively(item, field)
                    for another_result in more_results:
                        fields_found.append(another_result)

    return fields_found
get_recursively(data, ["properties"][0])
```

and the output was:

```
 [[{'name': 'BMW',
   'value': {'data': 'value1', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'type': 'String'}},
  {'name': 'Audi', 'value': {'data': True, 'type': 'Boolean'}}],
 [{'name': 'Volvo',
   'value': {'data': 'value1', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'type': 'String'}}],
 [{'name': 'Yamaha',
   'value': {'data': 'value1', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'type': 'String'}}],
 [{'name': 'prop2',
   'value': {'data': 'value1', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'type': 'String'}}]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and why did it fail to achieve the results you wanted?

Comment: `ONE property` but properties is an array?

Comment: Please share the code and error if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to implement this recursive solution is with backtracking. When no more `'groups'` keys are are found nested inside the root key, the `'name'` key value is matched with `groups_name` parameter, which is 'SportCar' in our case. If this condition is satisfied check for the values inside same `'groups'`  key's (i.e. 'SportCar' key's) `'properties'` key and match its `'name'` key value with the `properties_name` parameter (which is 'BMW' in our case). If this second condition is also true, then update the `'data'` key value inside the same `'properties'` key, as per requirements, or else return (for backtracking).

```
import json

json_data = open('myjson22.json', 'r')

data = json.load(json_data)

def get_recursively( myJson, groups_name, properties_name, value2):

    if 'groups' in myJson.keys():
        # As there are multiple values inside 'groups' key
        for jsonInsideGroupsKey in myJson['groups']:  
            get_recursively( jsonInsideGroupsKey, groups_name, properties_name, value2)

    if 'name' in myJson.keys():
        # check for groups name
        if myJson['name'] == groups_name:
            # check for properties name
            if myJson['properties'][0]['name'] == properties_name:
                # Update value. The changes will persist as we backtrack because
                # we are making the update at the original memory location
                # and not on a copy. For more info see deep and shallow copy.
                myJson['properties'][0]['value']['data'] = value2
    return

get_recursively(data,'SportCar','BMW','changedValue1')
get_recursively(data,'Speeders','prop2','changedValue2')
print data
```

my output:

{u'groups': [{u'name': u'SportCar', u'groups': [{u'name': u'Trucks', u'properties': [{u'name': u'Volvo', u'value': {u'data': u'value1', u'type': u'String', u'encoding': u'utf-8'}}]}], u'properties': [{u'name': u'BMW', u'value': {u'data': `'changedValue1'`, u'type': u'String', u'encoding': u'utf-8'}}, {u'name': u'Audi', u'value': {u'data': True, u'type': u'Boolean'}}]}, {u'name': u'MotorCycle', u'groups': [{u'name': u'Speeders', u'properties': [{u'name': u'prop2', u'value': {u'data': `'changedValue2'`, u'type': u'String', u'encoding': u'utf-8'}}]}], u'properties': [{u'name': u'Yamaha', u'value': {u'data': u'value1', u'type': u'String', u'encoding': u'utf-8'}}]}]}

prettified it will look as:

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "SportCar",
      "properties": [
    {
      "name": "BMW",
      "value": {
        "type": "String",
        "encoding": "utf-8",
        "data": "ChangedValue1"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Audi",
      "value": {
        "type": "Boolean",
        "data": true
      }
    }
      ],
      "groups": [
    {
      "name": "Trucks",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "Volvo",
          "value": {
            "type": "String",
            "encoding": "utf-8",
            "data": "value1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "MotorCycle",
      "properties": [
    {
      "name": "Yamaha",
      "value": {
        "type": "String",
        "encoding": "utf-8",
        "data": "value1"
      }
    }
      ],
      "groups": [
    {
      "name": "Speeders",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "prop2",
          "value": {
            "type": "String",
            "encoding": "utf-8",
            "data": "ChangedValue2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```